# Foreach и новый объект

Tags: c#

Вот к примеру такой код, он загружает картинки из файлов и считает максимальную ширину и суммарную высоту:

```
List<Bitmap> bitmapsList = new List<Bitmap>();
foreach (string fn in fileNames)
  {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(fn);  // Интересует вот эта строка
    bitmapsList.Add(bmp);
    if (bmp.Width > maxWidth) maxWidth = bmp.Width;
    totalHeight += bmp.Height;
  }
```

Вопрос: как будет правильней, создавать объект `Bitmap bmp` в цикле, или объявить его перед циклом? Что происходит с ним после прохода одной интерации цикла?

Comment: С объектом - ничего не происходит. Переменная - пропадает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Упрощенно можно считать что переменные, объявленные внутри блока ограниченного `{ }` существуют до тех пор, пока выполняется код этого блока. Как только управление передается за пределы блока, все локальные переменные блока удаляются.

С объектами иначе. Объект существует до тех пор, пока к нему можно получить доступ по ссылке. Когда ни одной живой ссылки не осталось, объект может быть удален сборщиком мусора.

В реальности механизм в обоих случаях сложнее, но для начального понимания этого достаточно.

В вашем коде, переменные объявленные внутри цикла будут пересоздаваться на каждой итерации. Ссылку на `Bitmap` вы кладете в `List` объявленный за пределами цикла, поэтому с ним ни чего не произойдет.

Создание объекта, происходит в момент вызова конструктора `new Bitmap(fn)`, и оно разумеется должно быть внутри цикла.

Что касается вопроса "как лучше?" - чем код понятнее, тем лучше, компилятор и Jit-компилятор в процессе работы все равно оптимизируют и изменят его так, как посчитают нужным и эффективным. Хотя надо отметить, что для языков на основе стековой машины, C# в их числе, присутствует рекомендация - объявлять переменную максимально близко к месту ее использования, т.е. если переменная используется только внутри итерации цикла и ее значение не участвует в последующих итерациях - объявляем ее внутри цикла, в противном случае вне цикла.

Ну и потратьте день другой, на целенаправленное изучение/повторение основ языка, принципов работы с памятью и сборки мусора в .NET, это реально нужно, если конечно вы планируете развиваться дальше в этом направлении. Вот [**тут**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/198316) есть отличный список литературы.

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать как душа желает, но JIT-компилятор при выполнении оптимизирует Ваш код. Скорее всего, будет создана одна переменная, на которую будет ссылаться код в цикле.

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите.

Текст `Bitmap bmp` объявляет ссылку на объект типа `Bitmap`. На каждой итерации цикла вы конструируете новый объект, и ссылка начинает ссылаться на этот объект (в результате присваивания).

Если ссылка объявлена за циклом, то при этом (начиная со второй итерации) ссылка больше не указывает на старый объект, оставшийся с последней итерации, и он становится разрешённым к сборке сборщиком мусора.

Если ссылка объявлена внутри цикла, то она умирает в конце каждой итерации, и объект опять-таки становится доступным сборщику мусора.

---

Технически, разница состоит в том, что при объявлении ссылки за циклом старое значение ещё доступно в начале цикла, а также последнее значение доступно после окончания цикла. Обычно такая доступность не нужна или даже вредна: вы можете забыть проинициализировать переменную, и будете работать со старым объектом вместо нового.

Пример:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
foreach (string fn in fileNames)
{
    if (condition)
        bmp = new Bitmap(fn);
    // else вы работаете со старым объектом
}
```

В случае, если `bmp` объявлять внутри, такое не пропустит компилятор.

Поэтому обычно рекомендуют объявлять переменные в самом вложенном блоке, где только можно, чтобы защититься от глупых ошибок.

---

Уточнение: как верно подсказывает @Zufir в комментарии, ссылка на `bmp` сохраняется в `bitmapsList`, так что объект не будет съеден в этом случае сборщиком мусора. Но без этого сохранения объект был бы доступен для сборки.

Comment: "ссылка больше не указывает на старый объект, оставшийся с последней итерации, и он становится разрешённым к сборке сборщиком мусора." А разве в списке ссылка на "старый объект" не сохранится?

Comment: @Zufir: Точно, сохранится! Но это потому, что ссылка внутри цикла копируется в список.